# Where-Object leaving blank rows

Tags: powershell

I'm again stuck on something that should be so simple. I have a CSV file in which I need to do a few string modifications and export it back out. The data looks like this:

```
FullName
--------

\\server\project\AOI
\\server\project\AOI\Folder1
\\server\project\AOI\Folder2
\\server\project\AOI\Folder3\User
```

I need to do the following:

- Remove the "\\server\project" from each line but leave the rest of the line
- Delete all rows which do not have a Folder (e.g., in the example above, the first row would be deleted but the other three would remain)
- Delete any row with the word "User" in the path
- Add a column called T/F with a value of "FALSE" for each record

Here is my initial attempt at this:

```cs
Get-Content C:\Folders.csv |
    % {$_.replace('\\server\project\','')} |
    Where-Object {$_ -match '\\'} |
    #Removes User Folders rows from CSV
    Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'User'} |
    Out-File C:\Folders-mod.csv
```

This works to a certain extent, except it deletes my header row and I have not found a way to add a column using Get-Content. For that, I have to use `Import-Csv`, which is fine, but it seems inefficient to be constantly reloading the same file. So I tried rewriting the above using `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content`:

```cs
$Folders = Import-Csv C:\Folders.csv
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    $Folder.FullName = $Folder.FullName.Replace('\\server\AOI\', '') |
        Where-Object {$_ -match '\\'} |
        Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'User Files'}
}
$Folders | Export-Csv C:\Folders-mod.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I haven't added the coding for adding the new column yet, but this keeps the header. However, I end up with a bunch of empty rows where the `Where-Object` deletes the line, and the only way I can find to get rid of them is to run the output file through a Get-Content command. This all seems overly complicated for something that should be simple.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: For your last attempt move your `Where{$_ -match '\\'}` and `Where{$_ -notmatch 'User Files'}` to one statement in the last line (and fix it to include the FullName property): `$Folders|Where{$_.FullName -match '\\' -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'User Files'}`

Comment: Thank you, TheMadTechnician! That worked in eliminating the blank lines. Now to add my column. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to TheMadTechnician for pointing out what I was doing wrong. Here is my final script (with additional column added):

```
$Folders= Import-CSV C:\Folders.csv 
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
 {
    $Folder.FullName = $Folder.FullName.replace('\\server\project\','') 
 } 
$Folders | Where-Object {$_ -match '\\' -and $_ -notmatch 'User'} |
Select-Object *,@{Name='T/F';Expression={'FALSE'}} |
Export-CSV C:\Folders.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a Table Array and pscustomobject.

```
#Create an empty Array
$Table = @()

#Manipulate the data
$Fullname = Get-Content C:\Folders.csv | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.replace('\\server\project\', '')} | 
    Where-Object {$_ -match '\\'} | 
#Removes User Folders rows from CSV
Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'User'}

#Define custom objects
Foreach ($name in $Fullname) {
    $Table += [pscustomobject]@{'Fullname' = $name; 'T/F' = 'FALSE'}
}

#Export results to new csv
$Table | Export-CSV C:\Folders-mod.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Oh, I saw you already have a solution as I was typing out my solution. In any case, I worked off your initial "get-content" method, so a slightly different method you can use to read a CSV and get out a new CSV without importing :)

Answer (score 0):

here's yet *another* way to do it ... [*grin*]

```
$FileList = @'
FullName

\\server\project\AOI
\\server\project\AOI\Folder1

\\server\project\AOI\Folder2
\\server\project\AOI\Folder3\User
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$ThingToRemove = '\\server\project'

$FileList |
    Where-Object {
        # toss out any blank lines
        $_ -and
        # toss out any lines with "user" in them
        $_ -notmatch 'User'
        } |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FullName = $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($ThingToRemove)
            'T/F' = $False
            }
        }
```

output ...

```
FullName       T/F
--------       ---
\AOI         False
\AOI\Folder1 False
\AOI\Folder2 False
```

notes ...

- putting a slash in the property name is ... icky [*grin*]
  that requires wrapping the property name in quotes every time you need to access it. try another name - perhaps "Correct".
- you can test for blank array items [lines] with `$_` all on its own
- the `[regex]::Escape()` stuff is really quite handy